# Best option for running java web service (rest based) (JRE/JDK vs Server JRE)

Tags: java, deployment, microservices

I was stumble upon two options while deploying java web service (rest api built using spring-boot and family).

1. install JRE/JDK and use -server argument for starting up service
   `java -server -classpath lib\*.jar -Denv=staging com.acme.pos.application.Application`
2. install server JRE from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html and use above java command

Can someone please answer this with the best practices perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These options are unrelated, Server JRE is a specific packaging for servers, to avoid having to install a full JDK with the associated security risks. Oracle explains this on the download page:

> The Server JRE includes tools for JVM monitoring and tools commonly required for server applications, but does not include browser integration (the Java plug-in).

You should do 2, as explained above, **and** maybe 1, which optimizes the JVM for server workloads, because of performance advantages. However, have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html: on the 64 bits JVM the server VM is the only one available.

Comment: When you say options are unrelated, does it mean that option selection should be based upon use case? Lets say, I just need for deploying a service on a VM, option 2 is most suitable one?

Comment: In my opinion, the Server JRE is the best option for dedicated servers so that's the one you should install on a server instead of a full JDK, whether you also add `-server` depends on the JVM you plan to use, 32 bits or 64 bits. However, on 64 bits JVMs the option is harmless, so you can always add it to benefit of the server-workload optimizations it enables. That's what we do, by the way.

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)